# CMake does not find the source directory (installing Eigen)

Tags: cmake, eigen, eigen3

I was installing the library [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php) on Ubuntu. I followed the instructions by creating a "build directory" alongside the downloaded source directory. That is, I have two directories: `eigen-eigen-1306d75b4a21` for source, and an empty `eigen-build` for build.

Then I did:

```
cd eigen-build
cmake ../eigen-eigen-1306d75b4a21/
sudo make install
```

An error occurred immediately after `make install` and it stops the installation:

```
CMake Error: The source directory "/home/username/something/eigen-eigen-1306d75b4a21" does not exist.
```

Obviously the directory exists. What is wrong with my CMake? (I don't know much about CMake. I observed some warnings during the second step, saying lots of things such as Qt4 are missing, but I don't think this is the cause, because of what the error message suggests.)

Comment: so your build directory is `/home/username/something/eigen-build`? Did CMake complain about anything?

Comment: are you shure this is not some kind of permissions error?

Comment: I had the same error. Path to source directory contained some special characters like 'ščťžýáí' so when I changed path, to something like `/home/user/project`, it worked.

Comment: The comment by @32cupo might be relevant (assuming the OP did not literally uses the directory `/home/username/something`). Independent of that, this should be retried with up-to-date (or more recent) versions of Eigen and cmake (according to the hash, the Eigen-version tried was 3.2.2, which was the latest stable when the question was asked, but is outdated meanwhile). Completely unclear which cmake version was used.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your directory does not include the  `CMakeLists.txt` file.

Comment: The source directory does have the `CMakeLists.txt` file.